# Colour Coded bullet and row?

Tags: list, status

Is it possible to have a color coded bullet for a list item as well as changing the row color? I've tried and I've found its either one or the other.[image]

Comment: You mean you would want to show list items in a bullet way on `all items` view page?

Comment: I've edited my original post.

Comment: You can try exploring `JSLink`